# Disable SSE4.1 when compiling TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I followed the instruction on TF's website and install the TensorFlow from the source code. I did not change any configurations, all are the default values.

When I run my program (which works fine when using the pre-complied TensorFlow 0.12 wheel), it gives me the following error

`F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:86] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.`

By default TensorFlow enables SSE4 support, I guess there is a way to disable it? Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: What build options did you pass to `bazel` when you built from source code? Also, does the string `sse4_1` appear in the output if you run `grep /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: @mrry I did not pass any options to it, the default is `$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`. Also there is no `sse4_1` in the `cpuinfo`, just `sse` and `sse2`.

Comment: @mrry, sorry, forgot to say that I also have `sse4a` in cpuinfo, but still not `sse4_1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c4b09b5df79625a70853fd66b5caa7dd92fb4d1f/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L130) in `tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl` is responsible for enabling SSE 4.1 instructions in all x86 builds. If you delete that line, the resulting build should work on your machine.