# How can I build libtensorflow.so for the Tensorflow Rust bindings without SSE?

Tags: tensorflow, rust

I've been trying to use the Tensorflow Rust community bindings on Ubuntu 16.04 32bit. The compilation succeeds, and I have a working `libtensorflow.so` file that
links properly with the Rust program, but as soon as I run the program I get the following error:

```
F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:35] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

I've tried several solutions, and I've successfully gotten the `libtensorflow_cc.so` shared library to work, but the same solutions that worked for that don't work for the `libtensorflow.so` shared library. I'm trying to compile the `r1.0` tag from the main tensorflow github repository.

The `tensorflow.bzl` doesn't have the line referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474136/disable-sse4-1-when-compiling-tensorflow) answer, so that solution wouldn't apply. I've also tried compiling with `bazel build --copt=-mno-sse ...`, but that also did not work. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what CPU do you have? Could it be possible that you are using the wrong target triplet?

Comment: I'm running it on a VM and my host has an i7. Another weird thing I noticed since this post was that `/proc/cpuinfo` lists SSE (all versions) as supported... maybe there is a difference in how its availability is checked?

Comment: Something is fishy there then, the latest SSE instructions are available on [Nehalem/Haswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4) for example. Here is [the code Tensorflow is using](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_info.cc) which is [called from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc#35)

Comment: You have a very strange definition of "and I have a working libtensorflow.so" if using the library results in an error...

Comment: Could you try using the master branch of the Rust bindings? It will (by default) download and install pre-compiled TensorFlow binaries, and might fix your issue.

Comment: @Shepmaster I meant that there were no compile or link errors... Its only causing an error at runtime. I also got the `libtensorflow_cc.so` (C++ bindings) file working without the runtime error.
@E_net4 I don't think Tensorflow offers precompiled 32bit binaries, so I have to compile it myself, but I'll check if using the master branch of the Rust bindings does anything.

Comment: You might be having additional difficulties from the fact that you have a 32-bit machine, which is not very common. Maybe the question would be better phrased as "How can I use the Rust bindings for TensorFlow on 32-bit Linux"?