# Problem after install tensorflow in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

ive installed tensorflow

But when i try to start it i give this error:

```
2018-11-10 19:07:16.129068: F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is too old for precompiled libraries. Or you compiled TF from source with SSE instructions enabled and your CPU does not support SSE instructions.

If you used precompiled libraries, you will need to compile from source without SSE instructions. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474136/disable-sse4-1-when-compiling-tensorflow/41477681#41477681) for more details.