# Tensorflow on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to install `tensorflow` on ubuntu 18.04. It appears to install correctly when I follow the pip install instructions given here
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
However I keep running into this particular error message when I do simple `import tensorflow as tf` command

```
 tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried the following

- pip3 and pip
- installing from source with `bazel`
- Conda

All three came back with the exact same error. Surely there must be an easy way to fix this or I'm missing something very basic. 
Could someone point out what could be off?

Comment: Did you attempt to disable SSE4 when you built it from source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable SSE4.1 when compiling TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474136/disable-sse4-1-when-compiling-tensorflow)

Comment: This is a hardware limitation, What CPU does the target machine use? Do you have packages for correct architecture? You'd need to compile it without support for SEE4.1.

Comment: trying out the suggestions given in the posted link, will post what I find back here.

Comment: The method worked. Though it took a while to compile